# Is it proper to put spaces around minus sign in Stylus?

Tags: css, webstorm, stylus

I have not found this info anywhere and my case is - I use [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) as my primary IDE for web projects. When I edit a [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) file and format it with default WebStorm format tool, it adds spaces after negative value minus sign so this:

```
.header
  background-position 0px -115px
```

turns into this:

```
.header
  background-position 0px - 115px
```

And as a result, when Stylus processor runs through this file, it thinks that I want to get a result of `(0 - 115)px` as a subtraction, so finally in CSS file it becomes this:

```
.header
  background-position -115px
```

Which is nor legit as a CSS rule neither correct for my case.

So the question is it correct at all to have a space after a minus sign at all in Stylus or even CSS?

Comment: I don't think the css will work correctly with a space after as it will treat it as two values rather than just -115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bug is WebStorm, please watch [WEB-10540](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10540)